# How to give Padding before slider value 0 and after slider value 100 in custom UISlider

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uislider

I need a custom slider something like below [image: customUISlider]

I need to start my slider after some padding, and need same padding after slider reaches end i.e;slider value 100, by filling same maximum and minimum track image of slider even in this padding area as shown in the above image.

In other words Slider has to start virtually after some padding and end before some padding value.
How to achieve this? any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: So if I read you straight, the actual minimum and maximum values are still 0 and 100 respectively?

Comment: @nickfalk Yes, but my value 0 has to start after little padding as shown in the picture and 100 is max value needs to end before some padding

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve it doesn't sound too hard: The slider CAN actually have a value below 0 and above 100 but you simply need to round the actual values off. Outside this it's "just" a question of finding what percentage of the slider's range you need to expand it with. i.e. will the actual slider span from -10 - 110 for instance...

Comment: @nickfalk i can do that but my requirement is like slider has to start from pt. 0 and has to end at the pt. 100, 1)initially if suppose slider value is 0 on load before 0 also some pink fill image should be visible and 2)when suppose user moves slider till 100 as soon as it reaches 100 the rest of space after 100 text has to fill with that pink color.

Comment: I might be daft, but if this is a custom component you could still achieve it the way I describe. You would however have to handle to set of values: One internal set for the slider that covers the values outside 0-100 and one external value that is returned within the range. If you check the internal value you can set it to min or max the moment it is outside the external min and max-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to provide a mapping function that converts a value to a slider setting, and vice versa. Thus you never use the slider value directly, only the mapped value.

You set the left value to -10 and the right to 110. The mapping f returns 0 for values <= 0, 100 for >= 100, and the real value for ant thing else.